# A better way on improving my roman numeral decoder

Tags: lua

Quick explanation, I have recently started using codewars to further improve my programming skills and my first challenge was to make a roman numeral decoder, I went through many versions because I wasnt satisfied with what I had, So I am asking if there is an easier way of handling all the patterns that roman numerals have, for example I is 1 but if I is next to another number it takes it away for example V = 5 but IV = 4.

here is my CODE:

```
function Roman_Numerals_Decoder (roman)
    local Dict = {I = 1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000}
    local number = 0
    local i = 1
    while i < #roman + 1 do
        local letter = roman:sub(i,i) -- Gets the current character in the string roman
        if roman:sub(i,i) == "I" and roman:sub(i + 1,i + 1) ~= "I" and roman:sub(i + 1,i + 1) ~= "" then -- Checks for the I pattern when I exists and next isnt I
                number = number + (Dict[roman:sub(i +1,i + 1)] - Dict[roman:sub(i,i)]) -- Taking one away from the next number
                i = i + 2 -- Increase the counter
        else
            number = number + Dict[letter] -- Adds the numbers together if no pattern is found, currently checking only I
            i = i + 1
        end
    end
    return number
end

print(Roman_Numerals_Decoder("MXLIX")) -- 1049 = MXLIX , 2008 = MMVIII
```

at the moment I am trying to get 1049 (MXLIX) to work but I am getting 1069, obviously I am not following a rule and I feel like its more wrong then it should be because usually if its not correct its 1 or 2 numbers wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is slightly different: you need to consider subtraction when the previous character has less weight than the next one.

```
 function Roman_Numerals_Decoder (roman)
    local Dict = {I = 1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000}
    local num = 0
    local i = 1
    for i=1, #roman-1 do
        local letter = roman:sub(i,i) -- Gets the current character in the string roman
        local letter_p = roman:sub(i+1,i+1) 
        if (Dict[letter] < Dict[letter_p]) then
            num = num - Dict[letter] -- Taking one away from the next number
            print("-",Dict[letter],num)
        else
            num = num + Dict[letter] -- Adds the numbers together if no pattern is found, currently checking only I    
            print("+",Dict[letter],num)
        end
    end
    num = num + Dict[roman:sub(-1)];
    print("+",Dict[roman:sub(-1)], num)
    return num
end

print(Roman_Numerals_Decoder("MXLIX")) -- 1049 = MXLIX , 2008 = MMVIII
```

Comment: that is really interesting, I didn't think of it as weights and from what I could tell from testing other roman numbers it works for pretty much all of them, thanks I have received some new knowledge!